# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64. While using static library

Tags: ios, symbols, arm64, openscenegraph, osgearth

I'm building a demo project which uses a 3d engine names "OpenSceneGraph" writing in C++, this engine provides tens of .a static library files after building. while I use those .a files in my xcode project, errors appeared

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
referenced from: in xxx.a    
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

I checked those .a files by using "lipo -info" command, they all support arm64 architecture. I got confused now.

Comment: What are the undefined symbols and what library is supposed to provide them?  Are there other error/warning messages in your link log?  Have you tried creating a link map while building to see exactly what is being included?

Comment: What iOS build recipe are you following?

Comment: Thank you guys, the problem solved by adding more .a files.